# Is there a way to add new files with a batch files?

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to add new files with batch files? I am looking to add new files alongside new folders. They would be the same files that you can retrieve by right-clicking white space in file explorer and clicking new... whatever.

This works for me for adding folders

```
@echo off
title New Project
set /p x= 
mkdir %x%

md "%x%"
md "%x%\1 Project Infomation"
md "%x%\2 Specifications and Intentions"
md "%x%\3 Workspace Files"
md "%x%\3 Workspace Files\_tempfiles"
md "%x%\4 Finalized Project Files"
md "%x%\5 Billing and Invoices"
```

what I want is something like this

```
@echo off
title New Project
set /p x= 
mkdir %x%

md "%x%"
md "%x%\1 Project Infomation"
md "%x%\1 Project Infomation\%x%PInfo.docm"
md "%x%\2 Specifications and Intentions"
?? "%x%\2 Specifications and Intentions\%x%Specs.docm"
md "%x%\3 Workspace Files"
?? "%x%\3 Workspace Files\%x%Workspace.3dm"
?? "%x%\3 Workspace Files\%x%Workspace.ai"
?? "%x%\3 Workspace Files\%x%Workspace.pdf"
?? "%x%\3 Workspace Files\%x%Workspace.dxf"
md "%x%\3 Workspace Files\_tempfiles"
md "%x%\4 Finalized Project Files"
md "%x%\5 Billing and Invoices"
```

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest way to do this be to create a set of empty template files in a known location, and just copy them and rename using your batch file?

Comment: Yeah, that might be best.

Comment: Use a redirection with any command that not show any output. For example: `cd . > "%x%\2 Specifications and Intentions\%x%Specs.docm"`

Comment: Or `Type Nul>"%x%\3 Workspace Files\%x%Workspace.3dm"`

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to create file. For your case, the simplest method is to

```
echo [randomText]>>"%x%\3 Workspace Files\%x%Workspace.3dm"
```

However, this creates a file with the length of `len(randomText) + 2`. To make the file 0 bytes, use this recommended by Compo instead:

```
type nul>"%x%\3 Workspace Files\%x%Workspace.3dm"
```

`nul` is a special device that removes everything sent into it, that is, `nul` == nothing. So you basically type nothing into a file.(Just create it)